# How to programmatically input answer for user prompt?

Tags: emacs

Some emacs functions takes a user input string as argument. For example, `M-x search-forward`, takes a user input string and search for it in buffer.

There are some search string that I uses frequently. Hence I would like to make my own function and hard-code this search string as a parameter for search-forward. For this function search-forward, this is easy because this function's function parameter list has a parameter for search string, as in its defun declaration: `(search-forward STRING &optional BOUND NOERROR COUNT)`. I can just pass the string into STRING paramater.

But for some other function that does similar string search, it does not specify the search string as a parameter. For example, in Magnar's multiple-cursor library, `mc/mark-all-in-region-regexp`, is a function that search for regexp string provided by user. I would like to make my own short-cut function that takes a fixed string, say, "abc". However, `mc/mark-all-in-region-regexp` 's parameter list does not have a parameter for search string. Here is the function parameter list: `(mc/mark-all-in-region-regexp BEG END)`. It only has parameter for the region begin and end position. However, if you execute it as a M-x command, i.e. `M-x mc/mark-all-in-region-regexp ENTER`, then it prompt you to enter the search string.

My question is, how do I write my function, to pass my search string into `mc/mark-all-in-region-regexp`?

My initial trial is like this. But not achieving what I expected.

```
(defun my-mc-mark-non-empty-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (mc/mark-all-in-region)
  (insert-string "abc")
  )
```

Comment: Consider modifying your question so that it clearly relates to Magnar's library `multiple-cursors` and provide an example of before and proposed after so that the readers of this thread can suggest potential solutions to the issue.  Also, you probably don't want to attract the `regex` tag crowd because the majority will probably know nothing about Magnar's library -- i.e., they may not even use Emacs.

Comment: Question is not clear. give some example of inputs and outputs you desire.

Comment: @Drew, its updated now

Comment: @lawlist its updated now

Comment: @nAviD its updated now

Comment: Magnar already added that as a third parameter on April 3, 2015:  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/blob/master/mc-mark-more.el -- see line 327.  Consider upgrading the entire multiple-cursors library to the latest version.  Here is the commit:  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/commit/72b4bf3911cc18e87a80b2152a6f707d12f2b531

Comment: That will solve my problem then. But to generalize, if there are other library function without string parameter, are there workaround to take user input without using parameter?

Comment: You need to create a new function or modify the existing function just like Magnar did in the commit that is the second link in my previous comment.  If you want to put the new function in your `.emacs` file (instead of modifying the source directly), you may need to `(require ...)` the library before redefining a function contained within that library.  You may also need to re-byte-compile if you modified the source directly.

Comment: The following link contains an example to programmatically input a yes/no response requested by the user (which is kind of semi-related to your question), but there are already 7 upvotes to the comment by Drew wherein he stated don't do that:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19077/how-to-programmatically-answer-yes-to-those-commands-that-prompt-for-a-decisio

Comment: I think these discussions answers my doubts already. If you like, you can put them in a answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When crafting a programmatic solution that deals with a function originally designed to request input from the user, it is generally advisable to devise a means to pass a value in the form of an argument or have the value derived from a variable.

For example, the author of the function at issue previously created an additional argument in a commit on April 3, 2015 -- the following is the `diff` -- i.e., `-` means removed, `+` means added.

```
-(defun mc/mark-all-in-region (beg end)
+(defun mc/mark-all-in-region (beg end &optional search)
   "Find and mark all the parts in the region matching the given search"
   (interactive "r")
-  (let ((search (read-from-minibuffer "Mark all in region: "))
+  (let ((search (or search (read-from-minibuffer "Mark all in region: ")))
         (case-fold-search nil))
     (if (string= search "")
         (message "Mark aborted")
```

The following link contains an example to programmatically input a yes/no response requested by the user (which is kind of semi-related to your question), but there are already 7 upvotes to the comment by Drew wherein he stated don't do that:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19077/how-to-programmatically-answer-yes-to-those-commands-that-prompt-for-a-decisio